# A new sufficient condition for $\lim_{(y,v,t)\rightarrow (x,d,0)} \frac{f(y+tv)}{t^m}=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be **infinitely differentiable real function**. Suppose that for a fixed $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{d} \in\mathbb{R}^n$, with $\mathbf{d}\not = \mathbf{0}$, we have $$  \ \partial^{\alpha} f\ \left(\mathbf{x}\right) {\mathbf{d}}
^{\alpha} \ = 0 $$ for all $|\alpha|\leq m.$ I'm pretty sure that $$ \lim_{(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{v},t)\rightarrow (\mathbf{x},\mathbf{d},0)} \dfrac{f(\mathbf{y}+t\mathbf{v})}{t^m}=0.$$ How can I prove it?

Note that this result is stronger than the converse of the related question: [If $f$ vanishes sufficiently fast at $x_0$ does this imply that all derivatives vanish as well?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008338/if-f-vanishes-sufficiently-fast-at-x-0-does-this-imply-that-all-derivatives).

Comment: What do you mean "for fixed $x,d \in \mathbb{R}^n, d^jf(x)d^j = 0$ for $j \leq m$"? Notation is unclear.

Comment: It is the "multi-index notation" for $d^j \  \partial^j f(x) = 0 $ for $j \leq m.$ This is explained in the wikipedia page <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series> at section **Taylor series in several variables**.

Comment: OK, I understand the notation now (and will remove the comments above to make space for discussion) :)

Comment: Thank you for your huge contribuition!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question need more assumptions to be true, since $\lim_{(y,t)\to 0} \frac{f(y+t)}{t}= 0$ does not hold for $f(x) = x^2$, even though $f(0)=f'(0)=0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: (For instance along $y=t^{1/4}$)

Comment: That explains the difficulty to prove this!  The result looks reasonable, but does not hold.

Comment: On the other hand if you exchange $y$ by $y(t)$ with $y(0)=x$ and $\frac{y(t)-y(0)}{t}$ bounded (for instance if $y(t)$ is differentiable at $t=0$) then the theorem is true under the minor assumption that $f$ be $m−1$-times differentiable in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $m$-times differentiable in $x$, due to the Taylor Theorem for Fréchet diferrentiable functions. Indeed you don't need $f$ to be $m+1$-times differentiable as one might expect, due to the version of the Taylor Theorem given in H. Cartan - Differential Calculus, which works under weaker hypothesis (Theorem 5.6.3, p. 71).

Comment: Oh, Gosh! That last result make me feel hope in my other result that I was needing to prove! I think I can make my result true! Thank you!

Comment: Actually I misunderstood you notation. I thought it implied in $D^jf(x)=0$ for all $1\leq j\leq m$, which is needed for my comment to be true. Either that or $\frac{d^jf(y(t)+vt)}{dt^j}=0$ on $t=0$, for all $1\leq j\leq m$ with $y(t)$ $m$-times differentiable. Sorry for the false hope xD.

Comment: Maybe you could post your result directly here and we can prove it or give a counterexample in case it is false.

Comment: $$  \sum_{|\alpha|=j} \partial^{\alpha} f\ \left(\mathbf{x}\right) {\mathbf{d}^\alpha} = \dfrac{d^j}{d t^j} (f \circ \lambda) (t), $$ where $\lambda (t) = x+t d $, right?
About your suggestion; yeah... I think I will post here after strugling a litle more. Hahahaha

Comment: Yes, the formula above is right indeed. Ok, no problem ;).